# Using a Kinect 2.0 Camera to measure the size of tree saplings?

Tags: open-source, camera

I'm a plant physiology PhD student, and I recently got a Kinect 2.0 camera.

I've been thinking about how to use this in a field application for my research. I have a planned project that will involve transplanting a few hundred saplings and estimating this aboveground mass before and after the field experiment.

Past projects in this style have historically used traditional photos from two angles to estimate tree biomass.

I'm curious if the Kinect camera could be more accurate and faster, since it could theoretically cut out the photo processing intermediate steps and estimate the canopy dimensions with high resolution.

I'm going to check out the Beginning Kinect Programming book by J Webb and J Ashley, but I was curious if anyone has software recommendations for estimating the shape (and calculating the size) of an irregular 3D object like a tree sapling using the Kinect depth camera.

I have to admit that I have no experience with programming, but I'm very excited to learn and I could use recommendations on software that can achieve this, or that could give me a start!

Comment: Hey Glorfindel, I appreciate the feedback but I'm struggling to make this an appropriate on-topic question (and maybe that's the root of the problem). I've defined a specific task (measuring the dimensions of trees using a specific piece of hardware) and I'm looking for recommendations on ready-to-use or general software that would help me to do that task. Do I need to more specifically define my objective requirements? I thought that I was looking for a specific software (as per the help center page re: on-topic posts), since I've already determined the technology that I'm planning to use.

Comment: Yeah, maybe that comment was a little misplaced, sorry for that. Please read the [question quality guidelines](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/336/23377) for what is desired in a good question for this site.